# Further from Cauchy inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire and$ M(R)=sup_{|z|=R}|f(z)|$ and $A(R)=supn_{≥0}|a_n|R^n$ where $a_n$ = $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$. Prove that $2A(2R) ≥ M(R)$

I tried to approach this question the same way as the Cauchy inequality but failed. I also tried to use Cauchy integral but failed too. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$M(R) \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|R^n= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|(2R)^n/2^n \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A(2R)/2^n = 2A(2R).$$